# Criar um dicionário a partir de uma lista

Tags: python

Tenho a seguinte lista:

```
msg = ['CAD400','Uma Filial...','Solucao:','O campo...','','LIB310','A Filial...','Solucao:','Foi identificado...','Foi corrigido...','','PAG302','Mudanca...','Solucao:','O erro...','O programa...','Programa alterado...']
```

Quero um dicionário com os dados da lista da seguinte forma:

```
msg_nova = {'CAD_001': ['Uma Filial...','Solucao:','O campo...'],'REC_002': ['A Filial...','Solucao:','Foi identificado...','Foi corrigido...'],'PAG_003': ['Mudanca...','Solucao:','O erro...','O programa...','Programa alterado...']}
```

Já tentei várias formas e não consegui fazer com que as descrições de cada programa(CAD, REC, PAG) estejam vinculadas respectivamente a cada um. Consegui até criar as chaves mas as descrições ficam cada uma separadas em uma lista.

Comment: Não vejo como da lista inicial chega  ao resultado proposto. Porque `['A Filial...'` fica associado ao `REC_002` e não `LIB310` ? Explique melhor a forma como se associam os valores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode varrer a lista vasculhando itens prefixados com `CAD`, `PAG` ou `LIB`. Caso o item possua algum dos prefixos, uma nova chave é incluída em um dicionário e seu valor (uma lista) preenchido até que uma nova chave seja encontrada.

Segue uma possível solução:

```
msg = [ 'CAD400','Uma Filial...','Solucao','O campo...','','LIB310','A Filial...','Solucao','Foi identificado...','Foi corrigido...','','PAG302','Mudanca...','Solucao','O erro...','O programa...','Programa alterado...']

prfx = ['CAD','PAG','LIB']
dic = {}
key = ''

for m in msg:
    for p in prfx:
        if p in m:
            key = m
            dic[key] = []
            break
    if m != key:
        dic[key].append(m)

print(dic)
```

Saída:

```
{'LIB310': ['A Filial...', 'Solucao', 'Foi identificado...', 'Foi corrigido...', ''],
 'PAG302': ['Mudanca...', 'Solucao', 'O erro...', 'O programa...', 'Programa alterado...'],
 'CAD400': ['Uma Filial...', 'Solucao', 'O campo...', '']}
```

Comment: Lacobus, quase perfeito mano, digo quase porque ainda não tive um tempinho pra identificar o porque não está saindo organizado no dicionário a ordem em que está na lista, a chave CAD400 está na última sequencia. De qualquer forma já está muuuito bom.

Comment: @NJAGO: Não é possível controlar a ordem dos pares (chave/valor) dentro de um [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Porém, você pode converter seu dicionário para uma lista de [`tuplas`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) para tornar essa ordenação possível. Referência: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-by-value).

Comment: Perfeito @Lacobus, muito obrigado.

Comment: Como @Lacobus disse, o `dict` não garante a ordem das chaves, mas é possível usar [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) junto com `sorted` para criar um dicionário ordenado.

Comment: @ThomazSoares: O `OrderedDict` implementa a técnica de converter para `tuplas` para realizar a ordenação.

Comment: @Lacobus, a diferença é que o `OrderedDict` é uma subclasse do `dict` e possui todas suas funções. Ou seja, da pra acessar os valores por chave `dic['CAD400']` ou `dic.get(''CAD400')`.